# Eigen, wrong use of comma initializer with different types

Tags: c++, math, matrix, linear-algebra, eigen

This is what I am trying to do:

```
Eigen::MatrixXd extended_points(4,4);
extended_points <<
    Eigen::Vector3d(-0.8, -0.8, 1.0).normalized(), 1.0,
    Eigen::Vector3d( 0.8, -0.8, 1.0).normalized(), 1.0,
    Eigen::Vector3d( 0.8,  0.8, 1.0).normalized(), 1.0,
    Eigen::Vector3d(-0.8,  0.8, 1.0).normalized(), 1.0;
```

This is an assertion that is failing in Eigen:

```
Eigen::CommaInitializer<MatrixType>& Eigen::CommaInitializer<MatrixType>::operator,(const Scalar&) [with XprType = Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>; Eigen::CommaInitializer<MatrixType>::Scalar = double]: Assertion `m_currentBlockRows==1' failed.
```

The Eigen documentation seems to suggest this is ok:
https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialAdvancedInitialization.html

I am confused.

Comment: Could you clarify which order you want the elements to be in `extended_points` (one per row or one per column)?

Comment: The structure of the matrix should mimic the syntax. i.e each float vector pair is one row of the matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible issue: Isn't Eigen::Vector3d a column vector?
As a workaround, you can try RowVectorXd as in the documentation.

Comment: This is indeed the fix